# ingress not enabled in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I enabled `ingress` on `minikube`

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>minikube addons enable ingress
  - Using image k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.44.0
  - Using image docker.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.5.1
  - Using image docker.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.5.1
* Verifying ingress addon...
* The 'ingress' addon is enabled
```

But when I list it, I don't see it

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>minikube kubectl -- get pod -n kube-system
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-74ff55c5b-px725            1/1     Running   0          13d
etcd-minikube                      1/1     Running   0          13d
kube-apiserver-minikube            1/1     Running   6          13d
kube-controller-manager-minikube   1/1     Running   0          13d
kube-proxy-h7r79                   1/1     Running   0          13d
kube-scheduler-minikube            1/1     Running   0          13d
storage-provisioner                1/1     Running   76         13d
```

Is the `ingress` not enabled? How can I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recreated this situation and got the same situation. After execution the command:

```
minikube addons enable ingress
```

I have same output as yours:

```
  - Using image k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.44.0
  - Using image docker.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.5.1
  - Using image docker.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.5.1
* Verifying ingress addon...
* The 'ingress' addon is enabled
```

I have also the same output, when I have executed:

```
minikube kubectl -- get pod -n kube-system
```

---

**Solution:**
First you can list namespaces with command:

```
minikube kubectl get namespaces
```

And your output should be as follow:

```
NAME              STATUS   AGE
default           Active   4m46s
ingress-nginx     Active   2m28s
kube-node-lease   Active   4m47s
kube-public       Active   4m47s
kube-system       Active   4m47s
```

The ingress should be in the `ingress-nginx` namespace. Execute:

```
minikube kubectl -- get pods --namespace ingress-nginx
```

and then your output should be as follow:

```
NAME                                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx-admission-create-nqnvj        0/1     Completed   0          2m56s
ingress-nginx-admission-patch-62z9z         0/1     Completed   0          2m55s
ingress-nginx-controller-5d88495688-ssv5c   1/1     Running     0          2m56s
```

**Summary - your ingress controller should work, just in a different namespace.**